# Where do I add this Ticket Reservation step during Checkout?

Tags: checkout, magento2.3, payment-gateway, guest-checkout

I am implementing a Cruise Ship reservation website on Magento 2.3. 
I'm unsure in which modules or files I have to implement steps 3 and 5 below?

(User flow through website)

1. Guest browses through Cruises available. Picks one by Adding to Cart. Clicks "Checkout"
2. Guest gives passenger names and addresses, captured on the Review & Payments checkout page. Clicks "Place Order"
3. **System has to connect to the Cruise Provider via API and place a "hold" reservation**
4. On successful "hold" reservation, System has to process the payment through payment gateway
5. **On successful payment, System has to connect to the Cruise Provider and ask for "hold" reservation to be converted to "confirmed" reservation.**

I have the Cruise Provider API (which is in SOAP) - so no problem here.

Which modules should I override, or in which files do I write my code to do Steps 3 & 5?

Comment: obviously, the step 3,4 would be together with step 2. and step would be managed from the backend.

Comment: Thanks @magefms for your reply. Do you mean I have to handle the steps 3 &4 in the view/frontend/templates/onepage.phtml  file?   Pardon me if its obvious, I'm a newbie and trying to find my way around.

Comment: @magefms, if you are still reading this. I'm trying to put my step 3 in an observer. I'm looking at the **checkout_cart_add_product_complete** event. This also means i have to change my flow a bit. Would you advise putting this step 3 in an observer?